# Golang swagger client with multiple responses

Tags: go, swagger

How can I generate a client from swagger to use it in a golang project that handles different response codes? Now I can get one that handle just success response (200).

My swagger file contents:

```
post:
      summary: sending messages
      description: send messages
      operationId: SendMessage
      parameters:
        - in: body
          required: true
          name: body
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Request'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Response1'
        400:
          description: Bad request
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Response2'
```

generate with:

```
docker run --rm -it -e GOPATH=/go -v "$(pwd):/work" -w /work quay.io/goswagger/swagger:latest generate client -f "./api/swagger-sender.yaml" -A Sender -
t internal/service/sender/client/gen
```

and all I get in client code is just one method to send message:

```
func (a *Client) SendMessage(params *SendMessageParams, opts ...ClientOption) (*SendMessageOK, error)
```

As you see only one type returned: `*SendMessageOK` and no one `*SendMessageBadRequest`

It looks like I can`t use go-swagger to generate desired client?

Answer (score 0):

SendMessageBadRequest is an error too and SendMessage will return it as the error
The only you need is to check the type of error and if it is SendMessageBadRequest then you`ve got 400